# Create a reusable ngDialog template

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-dialog

I want to create a reusable template for my application.

From what I understand, you can't pass the title and the body to ngDialog.

What I need is something like this :

```
<div>
<h2>{{ TITLE }}</h2> <- Dynamically pass this value
{{ BODY }} <- Dynamically pass this value

    <div class="ngdialog-buttons">
        <button type="button" class="ngdialog-button ngdialog-button-secondary" ng-click=closeThisDialog("Cancel")>Cancel</button>
        <button type="button" class="ngdialog-button ngdialog-button-primary" ng-click=confirm("OK")>OK</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is my controller :

```
$ngDialog.openConfirm({
            template: 'components/views/dialog/deletePopup.html',
            className: 'ngdialog-theme-plain popup',
            closeByEscape: true
        }).then( ...
```

How do I achieve this ? This way I could use the same html file across my application.

Edit : I have the same project in ionic/cordova too, and ionic is way easier. I wonder why it's so hard with angular.

Answer (score 0):

Use the behavior in the same controller will allow you to access the model and you will be able to change the title and body

Comment: Is it the recommended way ? Or the recommended way is to create separate html template files ?

Answer (score 0):

```
            ngDialog.openConfirm({
              template: 'views/alertTemplate.html'
            });
```

and in the views folder put the **alertTemplate.html** file:

for example:

```
<div class="alert-dialog-container">
  <div class="alert-dialog-body">
    Hello my dialog!
  </div>
  <div class="alert-dialog-footer">
    <button ng-click="confirm()">OK</button>
  </div>
</div>
```